# Change number to text format in excel in windows c#

Tags: c#, windows, excel

I am exporting data from datagridview to excel sheet. The data consists of both numbers and characters. The numbers are getting displayed at the right most side of the cell where as the characters at the left side. I am missing some number format. I want the numbers also to get displayed at let side of the cell.  below is the export to excel code.

```
 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
      Excel.Range oRange;

        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        Excel.Range aRangeSingle = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "A1");
        aRangeSingle.ColumnWidth = 37;

        Excel.Range aRangeSingle2 = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("B1", "B1");
        aRangeSingle2.ColumnWidth = 65;



        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        try
        {

            for (i = 0; i <= dataGridView2.RowCount - 1; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j <= dataGridView2.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
                {
                    DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView2[j, i];
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = cell.Value;//this has numbers also


                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("server not available while export to excel");
        }
```

Comment: You need to set the HORIZONTAL ALLIGNMENT Property of cells.

 oRange.HorizontalAlignment

Comment: Not an answer to your specific question, but take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059757/export-to-excel-output-modification/5059921#5059921. You can fill an Excel-range which is much faster then 2 for loops. Regarding your question: go with the solution of @andy. Should work like that.

Answer (score 0):

change your line as:

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = "'" + cell.Value;
```

if excel see a single quote in the beginning it assumes it as a TEXT. But calcuations won't work as a number in this case. If you want to use as number then align the cell to left

Comment: i tried this but on the excel i see a small mark on top left corner indicating warning that the number has been changed to text. Can i avoid that